# super() of python2.7 skips direct parents?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

When I tried to call the `bar()` of `class B` from `class C`, which is a direct subclass of `B`, it turned out that the `bar()` of `class A` was called. But I explicitly required that the `B` version should be used. How can the method be resolved to that of `A`?

```
class A(object):
    def bar(self):
        print('bar from A')

class B(A):
    def bar(self):
        print('bar from B')

class C(B):
    def bar(self):
        super(B, self).bar()

c = C()
# It should print "bar from B"
c.bar()
# But actually it prints "bar from A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `super(sub_class, instance).method()` means call the method `method` of the *parent* of `sub_class` on the instance `instance`. Since the parent of `B` is `A`, the result makes sense.

What you want is `super(C, self).bar()`.